# Can I get a new iOS on my 1st generation iPod touch?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, jailbreak

I've got a 1st generation iPod touch that won't run anything over iOS 3.1.
Is there any way to put something newer on it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that. Due to hardware limitations new iOS versions only run on newer devices which typically have faster processers, more RAM, and/or better graphics controllers, depending on the device.